# SAS Infile not reading any data rows

Tags: sas

I am a novice with SAS and am having trouble importing a CSV file. The information is in the following layout:

```
aircraft,duration,no_pasg,speed_ground,speed_air,height,pitch,distance
boeing,98.4790912,53,107.91568,109.3283765,27.41892425,4.043514571,3369.836364
boeing,125.7332973,69,101.6555886,102.8514051,27.80471618,4.117431699,2987.803924
boeing,112.0170008,61,71.05196088,,18.58938573,4.434043129,1144.922426
```

I run the code below and I get 0 observations (not expected) and 8 variables (expected). What am I doing wrong? I even tried putting the firstob=2 to skip the first row that contain headers but that hasn't helped

I appreciate the help.

```
DATA FAA_DATA1;
INFILE '~/Project/Data/FAA1.csv' dsd dlm=',' firstobs=2;
INPUT aircraft $ duration no_pasg speed_ground speed_air height pitch distance;
RUN;
PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

Comment: There should be a note in the log about how many lines SAS read from the file.  Sounds like it is not seeing the end-of-line characters and so thinks your file is one lone line. That would explain why FIRSTOBS=2 causes you to get 0 observations.  Try using the TERMSTR= option on INFILE statement. If you made the file using Excel on Mac then you should try using TERMSTR=CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it is not seeing the end-of-line characters and so thinks your file is one long line. That would explain why FIRSTOBS=2 causes you to get 0 observations. There should be a note in the log about how many lines SAS read from the file.

Try using the TERMSTR= option on INFILE statement. The normal end of line for Unix is TERMSTR=LF. The normal end of line for Windows is TERMSTR=CRLF.  If you made the file using Excel on a Mac then you should try using TERMSTR=CR.

For some reason Excel on a Mac still thinks that Mac OS uses CR as the end-of-line character for text files even though Apple converted the Mac OS to using Unix years ago.  There also should be an option in Excel when saving the file to save it as comma delimited but using normal end of line characters.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! I was so confused because I had a similar file that I didn't save on my Mac before using and I didn't have to use the TERMSTR option, your answer explains why. Strange. Thanks!